# In Shopify Hydrogen, the Image component triggers CSP

Tags: reactjs, shopify, content-security-policy, shopify-hydrogen

**The error**

*"Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive..."*

**Background**

I'm aware of the requirement for this security feature but my particular problem is specifically to do with Hydrogen's Image component.

Using Shopify Hydrogen (mostly demo store), there is a Product Card component.
Inside you'll find the following code...

```
return (
    <div className="flex flex-col gap-2">
      <Link
        onClick={onClick}
        to={`/products/${product.handle}`}
        prefetch="intent"
      >
        <div className={clsx("grid gap-4", className)}>
          <div className="card-image aspect-[4/5] bg-primary/5">
            {image && (
              <Image
                className="fadeIn w-full object-cover"
                sizes="(min-width: 64em) 25vw, (min-width: 48em) 30vw, 45vw"
                aspectRatio="4/5"
                data={image}
                alt={image.altText || `Picture of ${product.title}`}
                loading={loading}
              />
            )}
```

**The problem**

If I remove the image component and replace with <></> the security errors go away.
So I know it is to do with the Image component.  But I can't alter Shopify's component.

Note: I have checked the domains are permitted by the security policy - so this would appear to be an inline styles issue.

The dev tools unfortunately don't tell you where the CSP issue actually is.

**Question**

What can I do to satisfy the security requirements and safely use the Image component in Shopify's Hydrogen?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is highly likely that it is the "sizes" property which is being output as a style attribute on the image. This counts as inline style. Attributes are not nonceable and they can only be allowed by hashes if you also add 'unsafe-hashes'. Another option is to allow 'unsafe-inline', some may disagree, but it isn't that bad if you restrict the rest of your CSP, ref https://scotthelme.co.uk/can-you-get-pwned-with-css/.

Comment: Thank you for sharing the article - really interesting read.  Okay so I've indicated as answer because it is common place to allow unsafe for inline styles i.e. required for Angular.  It's difficult to accept that a security policy process that allows inline styles as unsafe, therefore creating a common place single weakness, is any sort of security policy at all.  But new to this and still learning.  Thanks again.